# Best architecture for a Python command-line tool with multiple subcommands

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am developing a command-line toolset for a project. The final tool shall support many subcommands, like so

```
foo command1 [--option1 [value]?]*
```

So there can be subcommands like

```
foo create --option1 value --

foo make file1 --option2 --option3
```

The tool uses the argparse library for handling command-line arguments and help functionality etc.

A few additional requirements and constraints:

- Some options and functionality is identical for all subcommands (e.g. parsing a YAML configuration file etc.)
- Some subcommands are quick and simple to code, because they e.g. just call an external bash script.
- Some subcommands will be complex and hence long code.
- Help for the basic tool should be available as well as for an individual subcommand:

  foo help
  Available commands are: make, create, add, xyz

  foo help make
  Details for the make subcommand
- error codes should be uniform across the subcommands (like the same error code for "file not found")

For debugging purposes and for making progress with self-contained functionality for minimal viable versions, I would like to develop some subcommands as self-containted scripts and modules, like

```
make.py
```

that can be imported into the main `foo.py` script and later on invoked as both

```
make.py --option1 value etc.
```

and

```
foo.py make --option1 value
```

Now, my problem is: What is the best way to modularize such a complex CLI tool with minimal redundancy (e.g. the arguments definition and parsing should only be coded in one component)?

**Option 1:** Put everything into one big script, but that will become difficult to manage.

**Option 2:** Develop the functionality for a subcommand in individual modules / files (like `make.py`, `add.py`); but such must remain invocable (via `if __name__ == '__main__' ...`).

The functions from the subcommand modules could then be imported into the main script, and the parser and arguments from the subcommand added as a subparser.

**Option 3:** The main script could simply reformat the call to a subcommand to subprocess, like so

```
subprocess.run('./make.py {arguments}', shell=True, check=True, text=True)
```

Comment: The python library 'click' provides this functionality

Comment: So does Typer, if you're used to FastAPI

Comment: I think your question is a lot bigger than the duplicate link.  `parents` is one lazy-man's way of defining the same argument(s) in multiple subparsers.  But lazy programmers also know they can write helper functions to perform repetitive tasks.  But I think SO is not a good forum for addressing program structure issues.  The scope is too  large, and too subject to opinions.  Once you've written a basic subparsers code you have exhausted the tools that `argparse` provides.  Running subcommands and partitioning in modules are not `argparse` issues.

Comment: Exactly. Best practice questions, if they're on topic on Stack Exchange at all, belong at [programmers.se], not here. Stack Overflow is only for questions about narrow, specific problems encountered during the practice of programming that are amenable to canonical answers.

Comment: Typer (and, for API purposes, FastAPI) look very promising! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your suggestions!

I think the most elegant approach is using Typer and following this recipe:

https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/subcommands/add-typer/

Answer (score 2):

I'm more used to answering questions about the details of `numpy` and `argparse`, but here's how I envisage a large package.

In a `main.py`:

```
import submod1
# ....
sublist = [submod1, ...]
def make_parser(sublist):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # parser.add_argument('-f','--foo')  # main specific
    # I'd avoid positionals
    sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd', etc)
    splist=[]
    for md in sublist:
         sp1 = sp.add_parser(help='', parents=[md.parser])
         sp1.set_default(func=md.func)  # subparser func as shown in docs
         splist.append(sp1)
    return parser
```

if **name** == '**main**':
parser = make_parser(sublist)
args = parser.parse_args()
# print(args) # debugging display
args.func(args)   # again the subparser func

In `submod1.py`

import argparse
def make_parser():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False) # check docs?
parser.add_argument(...)  # could add a common parents here
return parser

```
parser.make_parser()

def func(args):
    # module specific 'main'
```

I'm sure this is incomplete in many ways, since I've written this on the fly without testing.  It's a basic subparser definition as documented, but using `parents` to import subparsers as defined in the submodules.  `parents` could also be used to define common arguments for subparsers; but utility functions would work just as well.  I think `parents` is most useful when using a parser that you can't otherwise access; ie. an imported one.

`parents` essentially copies Actions from one parser to the new one - copy by reference (not by value or as a copy).  It is not a highly developed tool, and there have been a number of SO where people ran into problems.  So don't try to over extend it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) along with the [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

In short, create an abstract class called Command and make each command it's own class inheriting from Command.

Example:

```py
class Command():

    def execute(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class Command1(Command):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def execute(self):
        pass


class Command2(Command):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def execute(self):
        pass
```

This will handle execution of commands. For building, make a command factory.

```py
class CommandFactory():

    @staticmethod
    def create(command, *args):
        if command == 'command1':
            return Command1(args)
        elif command == 'command2':
            return Command2(args)
```

Then you'd be able to execute a command with one line:

```py
CommandFactory.create(command, args).execute()
```

Comment: Hmm - thanks for your effort! However, the problem is not adding subcommands - that is well supported by argparse. The main challenge is a modularization approach that eliminates redundancy regarding CLI arguments and documentation/help, while allowing to run the subcommands as individual Python scripts.